# Linq fail - A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I don't understand why I am getting this error. I'm also used to .NET throwing an actual error which I can debug. Instead I am getting the following in the output console:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
```

I have recreated the application and database several times. Oddly, it worked the first time (it was a different app and different db but the process was the same).

1. create 4.0 windows form app
2. create a .mdf database through vs
3. create tables on the db
4. create the linq to sql file and drag the table onto it.
5. enter linq code and run the code. I get the error already mentioned.

The actual code is:

```
// i changed the variable names before posting so if I spelled cats wrong thats not the problem
static public void Insert(Cat[] cats)
    {
        using (Cats.lsMapDataContext db = new lsMapDataContext(Global.db_path))
        {
            foreach (Cat cat in cats)
            {
                history history = new history();
                history.name = cats.name;
                history.breed = cats.breed;
                db.histories.InsertOnSubmit(history);
                db.SubmitChanges(); // i silently fail here because silent fails are cool and helpful
            }

        }
    }
```

Is there some common reason why it might be doing this? The database gets created in Documents for the user I am on (only one for this computer/admin). There are no special access rights that I know of.

Is there a way to hook into that dll so that I can debug it when it crashes? A pdb or something?

Comment: Can you look at the inner exception if it is not null and update this post with the inner exception error message?

Comment: I did not know what an inner exception was so I put a try catch around the bad line and it caught it which should provide me with enough info to fix it. The error message is "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\\...my_db.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share." -- thx man

Comment: It sounds like the database has a connection locking it, have you got the database file being used by any other applications? Are you editing the database in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

By inspecting `.InnerException` (or `.InnerException` of the `.InnerException` etc) you should be able to see the actual error.

You can do it by:

- debug the code and inspect the .InnerException directly in Visual Studio; or
- add a `catch` statement and write the error to the console;

  ```
  static public void Insert(Cat[] cats)
  {
   try {
      //Your code here
   } catch (Exception ex ) {
      Exception ex2 = ex;
      while( ex2.InnerException != null ) {
           ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
      }
      Console.WriteLine( ex.InnerException );
      throw;
   }
  }
  ```